# How frequently are avionics on large commercial aircraft updated?

Tags: safety, avionics, software

How frequently are avionics on large commercial aircraft updated? And how are the systems updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infrequently. Large fleets, lots of down time, lot of equipment to buy.

The fleets are cycled thru at a refittng center where the panels are disassembled and re-assembled. Here is [one example](http://aeronautical-engineers.com/partners/)

Comment: Though the post doesn't specify it is tagged with `software`, which wouldn't necessarily require lots of new equipment.

Comment: Well, being a hardware engineer, I was looking at from the hardware perspective.  I just had new hardware put in my airplane (solid state gyros, GPS/Nav/Com, Transponder, Engine Monitor). And today the software was updated in the gyros and GPS/Nav/Com, which I never had hardware before that could be updated like that.

Comment: Even software doesn't get updated that often (Databases like maps are a different animal) For example, avionics company A might only put out a software update from 6 months to 2 years, depending on the product.